# What is the difference between skel js and skeleton js

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, frameworks, grid, javascript-framework

Is there any difference between skeljs and skeletonjs?

Can anyone provide with useful learning guide, other than docs?

- [Skeljs](http://skeljs.org/)
- [Skeletonjs](http://www.getskeleton.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The first issue is that there is no Skeletonjs, it's called Skeleton. This is because it's not based on Java script, it only uses CSS.

SkelJS uses style sheets and Javascript, which is the main difference between the two projects. SkelJS also appears to provide cleaner degradation for browsers that don't support media queries or have JS enabled.

Which you prefer is really up to you. I would suggest following the examples and try them out. Also a quick search on YouTube will turn up some examples using skeleton. The SkelJS website has a very nice example that you can follow as well.